# Structuring of company frameworks on top of spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-starter

We use our own framework in our company, which is based on Spring and Wicket. The framework has a total of two artifacts:

1. our-framework-parent, which derives from spring-boot-dependencies in order to benefit from the dependency management of Spring boot
2. our-framework, which is derived from our-framework-parent and contains the wicket components (footer, header...), Spring base components (auth, filter, webconfig...).

Our repositories then derive from our-framework-parent and have our-framework as dependency (version is determined via the our-framework-parent).

We would now like to migrate to Spring Boot. This raises the question of whether we should simply let the our-framework-parent inherit from spring-boot-parent and pack the necessary starters (starter-web, starter-log4j...) directly into our-framework & otherwise leave the structure as it is.

Or should we not use a starter in our framework and instead create another artifact - for example our-framework-spring-boot-autoconfigure and our-framework-spring-boot-starter?

If our framework were not written in Spring, the case would be totally clear to me. Here, docs.spring.io also recommends the use of starters. However, it is completely unclear to me whether I should outsource everything individually in our case.

I look forward to answers.

Comment: In my previous experience, they had a similar parent created and then most of the microservices, use to extend on top of the parent. So the structure wise, I will suggest continue to maintain it. I will avoid creating so many libraries if they JUST extend spring. For the `our-framework` i believe will need some work since it is mix of Wicket and Spring. However I will suggest you to refactor to meet Spring and Spring-Boot here.. again ensure you are not too behind in the version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - unfortunately I can't read any recommendations/suggestions from it. What do you mean specifically by refactoring?